# typelist, mismatch number of template parameters

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming, typelist

```
template<typename TList/*TList - Alexandrescu's typelist*/>
class TheClass
{
  void foo_public  ( const TypeAt<TList, 0>& t0, const TypeAt<TList, 1>&t1 )
  {
    foo_private(t0, t1)
  }
  void foo_private ( const TypeAt<TList, 0>& t0, const TypeAt<TList, 1>&t1 )
  {
    /*do stuff with t1*/
    foo_private(t0);
  }

  void foo_public ( const TypeAt<TList, 0>& t0 )
  {
    foo_private(t0);
  }
  void foo_private( const TypeAt<TList, 0>& t0 )
  {
    /*do stuff with t0*/
  }
};

int main()
{
  typedef MakeList<int, int> TheList; //variant 1 - works fine
  TheClass<TheList> c;

  typedef MakeList<int> TheList; //variant 2 - compile error
  TheClass<TheList> c;
}
```

Apparently it happens because in the case #2 because the compiler can't compile `foo_public/private` methods holding two arguments because template `TypeAt<TList, 1>` is not valid for the list containing single type.

How can i solve this problem in generic way, without specializing `TheClass` for typelist of 1,2,3... elements? Maybe somekind of "SFINAE-way"?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Nawaz: i want to make a template serializator. Instance the template with typelist like `serializator< typelist<int, double, some_class> >` and then `serialize(10,12, reference_to_some_class_object)`

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE:** I supposed that template specialization is not a solution, because the class is much bigger than in the code you provide us (Because you focused the question on the problem, well done. Everybody here hates questions with thousands of lines of code, and a question like: "What's wrong?")

Have you access to C++11? If the answer is yes, not use loki-style typelists, use more simple variadic-templates-based typelists:

```
template<typename... Ts>
struct TypeList{};
```

The implementation of typelist operations are too much simple.

Even if you use loki-style typelists, or variadic template typelists, the solution for your problem is exactly the same: enable_if

```
template<bool CONDITION , typename T>
struct enable_if;

template<typename T>
struct enable_if<true,T> { typedef type T; };

template<typename T>
struct enable_if<false,T> {};
```

As you probably noticed, the false specialitation not defined a typedef `type` of type T. That means if you use `enable_if` in two places, one where the condition is true and one where the condition is false, only one of places will be generated. Why? Because you are using member `type` in both, but in false case its not defined.

See an example: (Supose we have a metafunction `is_floating_point` that checks if a given type is a floating-point type)

```
template<typename T>
typename enable_if<is_floating_point<T>::value , bool> are_equal( const T& a , const T& b)
{
   const T epsilon = 0.0001;

   return std::abs(a-b) < epsilon;
}

template<typename T>
typename enable_if<!is_floating_point<T>::value , bool> are_equal( const T& a , const T& b)
{
   return a == b;
}
```

In this example, `enable_if` is used to conditionally generate floating-point version of the comparison function.

But in your case there is a problem. The correct instantation of a template function can only deppends on its own argumments, as in the example (Depends on `T`, wich is a parameter of the function).
But this is not your case: The instantation of the one parameter overloads of `foo_private` and `foo_public` not depends on function argumments, depends on class argumment (The typelist).

In C++11 you can solve this problem writing the function as a template function, and passing the non-function condition (The typelist size in our case) as default value of the template:

```
  template<unsigned int size_of_list = SizeOf<TypeList>::value>
  typename enable_if<size_of_list > 1 , void>::type foo_public  ( const TypeAt<TList, 0>& t0, const TypeAt<TList, 1>&t1 )
  {
    foo_private(t0, t1)
  }
  template<unsigned int size_of_list = SizeOf<TypeList>::value>
  typename enable_if<size_of_list > 1 , void>::type foo_private ( const TypeAt<TList, 0>& t0, const TypeAt<TList, 1>&t1 )
  {
    /*do stuff with t1*/
    foo_private(t0);
  }
```

If you don't have acess to anything from C++11, you could try another way. Suppose we have a conditional type selector:

```
template<bool CONDITION , typename T , typename U>
struct conditional;

template<typename T , typename U>
struct conditional<true,T,U> { typedef type T; };

template<typename T , typename U>
struct conditional<false,T,U> { typedef type U; };
```

Another way to solve your overloads is to use a unmeanning type (Innaccesible by the user) in the case that the typelist only contains one type:

```
template<typename TList/*TList - Alexandrescu's typelist*/>
class TheClass
{

  class UnmeanningType {}; //This type must be private

  typedef typename conditional<SizeOf<TList>::value > 1 , TypeAt<TList , 1> , UnmeanningType>::type SecondArgType;

  void foo_public  ( const TypeAt<TList, 0>& t0, const SecondArgType& t1 )
  {
    foo_private(t0, t1)
  }
  void foo_private ( const TypeAt<TList, 0>& t0, const SecondArgType& t1 )
  {
    /*do stuff with t1*/
    foo_private(t0);
  }

  void foo_public ( const TypeAt<TList, 0>& t0 )
  {
    foo_private(t0);
  }
  void foo_private( const TypeAt<TList, 0>& t0 )
  {
    /*do stuff with t0*/
  }
};
```

With this approach, if the typelist only contains one type, the two args overload uses UnMeanningType as seccond arg type, wich the user (Theorically) don't knows. So, in theory, user can only use the one arg overload in that case.